# Adding a collision in Aliens.py in Pygame

Tags: python, function, for-loop, parameters, pygame

I'm having a problem adding a collision in the Pygame example aliens.py

I want to add a collision detection that makes the alien UFOs blow up when they collide against each other.

Here's the code of the collisions in the program:

```
# Detect collisions
        for alien in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, aliens, 1):
            boom_sound.play()
            Explosion(alien)
            Explosion(player)
            SCORE = SCORE + 1
            player.kill()

        for alien in pygame.sprite.groupcollide(shots, aliens, 1, 1).keys():
            boom_sound.play()
            Explosion(alien)
            SCORE = SCORE + 1

        for bomb in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, bombs, 1):
            boom_sound.play()
            Explosion(player)
            Explosion(bomb)
            player.kill()

        #for alien in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(aliens):
            #boom_sound.play()
            #Explosion(alien)
```

The last for loop is the one I created. I apparently need 3 parameters, but I'm not sure what other parameters are needed. Please Help!

Comment: Did you mean you want to detect collision between the alien UFOs ? And if they do collide, they should blow up ?

Comment: Yeah, so if two of the UFOs touch each other, they should blow up

Comment: I've added a snippet to show how to do collision detection for that, see my answer. I also edited your question a bit to make it clear that you wanted to detect collision between two UFOs.

Comment: No probs. Please accept the answer if you are satisfied :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual page of pygame.sprite (http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) There are actually 4 parameters, They are :

1. sprite : you want to check collision for this
2. group : check collision against these
3. dokill : indicates the action i.e. to kill or not to kill upon detecting collision
4. collided (optional) : the callback function used to detect collision

I'm guess you wish to detect collision between two alien UFOs. You would need something like this:

```
for a in aliens :
    for alien in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(a, aliens, 1):
        boom_sound.play()
        Explosion(alien)
```

Comment: When I got the error, it said I needed 3, but i'm not disagreeing with you. Hm, ill check it out, Thanks!

Comment: So when I add that snip it, the aliens explode instantly when spawned. Why is this happening?

Comment: I need to see the code for spawning the aliens to be sure why. My guess is that they are being spawned at the same location.